# Find all automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Since $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ is a cyclic group (ex. generated by $\left<1\right>$), all automorphisms will be determined by finding $\phi(1)$. Since we want an isomorphism, we map $1$ to a generator, since then $\phi(1)$ will generate $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$. The generators of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ are numbers less than $10$, and co-prime with $10$. Thus $\phi(1) \in \{1,3,7,9\}$. 
Then the following will be automorphisms: $$\phi(x) = x \pmod{10}, \\ \phi_{3}(x) = 3x \pmod{10}, \\ \phi_{7}(x) = 7x \pmod{10},\\ \phi_{9}(x) = 9x \pmod{10}$$
Is this correct? Do I have to prove that each of these are isomorphisms(automorphisms)?

Update: I figured out that we can check if they are isomorphisms, since they are very simple mappings. So $\phi(x)$ is just the identity map, so that is clear. 
Now we can check $\phi_{3}(x)$. It is bijective. For the homomorphism:$\phi_{3}(x+y) = 3(x+y)= 3x + 3y = \phi_{3}(x) + \phi_{3}(y).$ The same goes for the others.

Comment: This is correct. :) Except the first one. It has to be $1x$, not $0$. But your idea is correct that you have to send $1$ to a generator.

Comment: oh my bad, thank you! @stressed-out

Comment: Update looks good too. It is always possible to be more detailed (prove that $\phi_3$ is bijective, and point out that $3(x+y)= 3x + 3y$ is also valid modulo $10$ as it is in the integers), but I don't think you really need to here. Sometimes it's difficult to know where to draw the line, though, and the ultimate authoroty on where that line should go (at least if you want everything to go smoothly, without disputes) is whoever is correcting your exams, and later whoever is refereeing your articles.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, I actually could prove that it is a bijection, and I did in my exercises, but did not write it here. I will make sure to add the details since, as you said, it is clear but someone may want more explanation. thank you!